# How to get query log of events run by admins

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.8, logfile, laravel-9

I want to get all the queries that run by each Admin of my website.

I mean I need to get the url of the page that they're running query and also their user id and ip address.

But for doing this, I don't want to use Controller methods.

I need to do this as Middleware and apply it to all admin routes.

So how can I do this?

Would you please provide me some tips or guidelines about this?

Comment: `laravel-5.8` or `laravel-9`, which is it?

Comment: There's a great package for this: [Laravel activity logger](https://curatedphp.com/r/laravel-activity-logger-jeremykenedylaravel-logger/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

In the first flow, you have to create a custom middleware using this command

```
php artisan make:middleware Admin
```

Then add middle route in kernal file  :-  app  >>  Http  >>  Kernel.php

Add this in $routeMiddleware  array

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    'admin' => \App\Http\Middleware\Admin::class,
];
```

after that add this admin route middleware to our route

```
 Route::get('admin/routes', 'HomeController@admin')->middleware('admin');
```

You can put your logic in this controller, so whenever any route call from this   inside this route first call our middleware

For more explanation reference the below link :

1. https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/middleware
2. https://appdividend.com/2022/01/23/laravel-middleware/